# Does <md-tab> generated through ng-repeat get unique indices?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

`<md-tab>` elements within `<md-tabs>` get indices starting from 0.

```
<md-tabs>
    <md-tab label="Tab #1"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Tab #2"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Tab #3"></md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

So in the above case, the three tabs will receive indices 0,1 and 2 respectively.

In my application I have tabs with following basic structure:

```
<md-tabs>
    <md-tab label="Home"></md-tab>
    <md-tab ng-repeat="cat in categories" label="cat.title"></md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

The first tab is a static one,and the others are generated through `ng-repeat`. So will the tabs generated in this way get indices as in the previous case?

In particular, if I get 4 more tabs through `ng-repeat` will angular material give them indices starting with 1( Home tab is assigned 0 index)?

**Edit 1:**
By indices what I mean is that, I can activate a particular tab by setting the value of `md-selected` attribute to its index. 
So for example:

```
<md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex">
    <md-tab label="Tab #1"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Tab #2"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Tab #3"></md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

where `selectedIndex` is a variable on `$scope` and I can set its value to 0,1,2...n-1 where n is the total number of tabs.

I want to know if `<md-tab>` elements generated by `ng-repeat` will get such indices in sequence.

Comment: What do you mean for indices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments I found that the answer is NO.

For instance:

```
<md-tabs>
    <md-tab label="Home"></md-tab>
    <md-tab ng-repeat="cat in categories" label="cat.title"></md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

In the above case, the Home tab will get an index 0. If there are n tabs generated through `ng-repeat` they won't get separate indices from 1..n-1.